# Unbound field for an existing screen

Tags: acumatica

I have a requirement for displaying allocated quantity in line items grid in Sales Order screen SO301000. As this is display only field, it should be unbound field. I know I can create unbound field for new screen by setting PrimaryView and TypeName properties. But not sure for an existing screen.

Comment: Got the answer. Simply create a respective CacheExtension and without PXDB datatype declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare respective CacheExtension. Include your unbound field declaration without PXDB datatypes. DB in the type attribute name denotes whether the field is bound.

```html
#region UsrQtyAllocated
        public abstract class usrQtyAllocated : IBqlField { }
        protected Int32? _UsrQtyAllocated;
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Qty. Allocated")]
        public virtual Int32? UsrQtyAllocated { get; set; }
#endregion
```

Comment: you should still include the data type attribute in your field, however use PXDecimal (without the "DB") vs PXDBDecimal. Usually the data types have a version with the same attribute name, just without the DB in the name which will represent an unbound field.